# C# help. Call operations from classes

Tags: c#

```
 class Addition : Form1
{
        public string AdditionTotal(){
        string AdditionTotal;
        int num1 = int.Parse(txtFirstNumber.Text);
        int num2 = int.Parse(txtSecondNumber.Text);
        AdditionTotal = (num1 + num2).ToString();
        return AdditionTotal;
    }
    public AdditionEqual()                          //Throws an error here
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(AdditionTotal);
        int AdditionEqual = AdditionTotal;
        Addition frm2 = new Addition();
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

Form 1:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string AdditionEqual { get; set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Addition MyLaptop = new Addition();
        if (Add.Checked)
        {
           MessageBox.Show( this.AdditionEqual);                          
        }
```

Can someone please edit and tell me whats wrong with my code here? I need to use classes and radiobuttons to make a calculator. There's currently 1 error. It says the public AdditionEqual() needs to have a return type. Theres only 1 error but I dont know if the code will actually work after that's fixed. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

The function needs a return type. Your first method returns a string:

```
public string AdditionTotal(){
```

That `string` is indicating what datatype the function will return.

```
public AdditionEqual()
```

This function doesn't have that indicator. If you don't intend for the method to return anything, use `void`.

```
public void AdditionEqual()
```